# Finding out object filter specification for Inkscape objects

Tags: website-design, inkscape, filter

As in my other questions I am running Inkscape 0.91. I have become quite fond of using Inkscape to build my wireframes, so I have a question.

Let's say I applied a drop shadow filter to an object in Inkscape. So when I translate it to a website I want to use the CSS box-shadow to make it look like that object. Now is there anyway to get the specifications of the filter I applied to the object in the wireframe? I noticed in the Filter Editor dialog box you can see the blur color but other than that I'm drawing a blank.

I would be most appreciative if anyone could let me know if this is a possibility in Inkscape. In the mean time, I'll just take good notes!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter editor dialog box for drop shadow in Inkscape gives you information on color, composite, gaussain blur, offset and on what are all these effects applied. The color setting is the default effect visible in the filter editor dialog box. Below which there are other settings which can be edited. 
In the image below gaussian blur is selected and the std deviation is altered.[image: filter editor]

Comment: Oh okay cool! I didn't look thoroughly enough at the filter editor dialog box. I seen that when you click the offset or whichever you want information about you can edit it and such. Thank you much for making me take a second look and giving me more details!!